# How to use "node-gzip" for file instead of text

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, gzip

I am learning how to compress the file by JavaScript by using "node-gzip"(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gzip).
"node-gzip" README said the following when you can compressed text.
So I tried to change from 'Hello World' to fileA(ascii or binary file) , but it does not work.

How can I compress the file by usign "node-gzip".

** Nodejs and node-gzip is installed.

<"node-gzip" README>

```
const {gzip, ungzip} = require('node-gzip');
const compressed = await gzip('Hello World');
const decompressed = await ungzip(compressed);
console.log(decompressed.toString()); //Hello World
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use a text file instead of `'Hello World'` in your showing script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please set your text filename with the path to the following script.

```js
const text = fs.readFileSync("./sample.txt"); // or const text = fs.readFileSync("./sample.txt", "utf-8");
const compressed = await gzip(text);
const decompressed = await ungzip(compressed);
console.log(decompressed.toString());
```

- In this case, please include `const fs = require("fs");`.